# Versioning with endpoint V2 on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have the live version of my app deployed with its endpoints (no problem with that).
I also want to easily be able to test other versions (e.g. staging).

**With endpointV1**: no problem.

**With endpointV2**:
Everything works fine if I deploy to the live version (at https://[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com but does not work for other versions.

After deploying to staging at https://staging-dot-[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com the deployment is successful, but when the frontend calls the backend, the request is received by the backend (I can see it in the GAE logs and trace list), but it does not make it to or though endpointV2 and responds 404 NOT FOUND:

> "errors": [
>      {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "notFound",
>       "message": "\u003chtml\u003e\u003chead\u003e\n\u003cmeta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\"\u003e\n\u003ctitle\u003e404 NOT_FOUND\u003c/title\u003e\n\u003c/head\u003e\n\u003cbody text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff\u003e\n\u003ch1\u003eError: NOT_FOUND\u003c/h1\u003e\n\u003c/body\u003e\u003c/html\u003e\n"
>      }

I now use the following maven plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- deploy configuration -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>endpoints-framework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</plugin>
```

I have adjusted the versions in appengine.xml and in the Google Cloud plugin. How can I configure endpoint to work with a specific module version instead of only the main version?

Comment: What do you mean with "version"? Application version of endpoint version?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a project using endpoints1. Trying to migrate to endpoints2 seems to work if the project is deployed on playground project on appengine. Deploying the same project to a non-default version on the production project (eg, 1-dot-xxxx, while 2-dot-xxxx is the default and still using the old appengine stuff) and then accessing the 1-dot- version gives us a 404.

Comment: @Julien Can you please elaborate the answer ? I am facing the same issue after migrating to version v2.

Comment: @RafiqAhmad Per your request, I posted a short answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not really an answer, I saw this:

When deploying a legacy type endpoint (V1), everything works fine, https://3-dot-xx.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis will show the APIs deployed to version 3

When deploying a new type endpoint (v2), eg 2-dot-, it depends on the last V1 endpoint deployed on the version.

- if it is a new version with no V1 endpoint deployed before, it works and the new endpoint is shown on 2-dot-
- if there was a V1 endpoint deployed here before, it will show the old V1 apis and naturally generate a 404 when accessing, as the actually running GAE version is different
- if the version was never deployed at all (eg asdf-dot-), or using the default (without the -dot- etc), it will show the default version and access it correctly.
- if there never was a V1 service deployed, but a V2 service, it works fine when deploying a new V2 service

So, it seems like there is a bug that will prevent you from using stable names for testing / staging environments if you already had a V1 service running on them. It would be very helpful if someone from Google could confirm this bug and suggest an appropriate workaround before I have to do a lot of costly changes to change URLs.

Comment: That resolved it for me: I was using a staging version name that was used in the past with endpointV1. The problem disappears when using a fresh name. I consider that to be an endpointV2 bug... but easy enough to go around it once the problem is identified!

Comment: Using a new version name worked for me, but also after deleting the existing version (and the APIs were no longer accessible) and deploying again with endpoints V2

Comment: @AndréGodoy I tried to delete old test version to get new Endpoints V2 there but the V1 seems to still hang around and it is even browsable with API explorer !! - was there any special tricks involved when you deleted the version?

Comment: @JariK When deleting a version to deploy it again with Endpoints V2, I had to wait for about 24h to get it working. In a newer project this restriction didn't seem to apply, so I'm not sure about that. But since Google heavily relies on cache I think you should give it a try.

Comment: @AndréGodoy Thanks! Ah ok that might be it, now I didn't retry, just started to use a fresh new version name for development.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for me was: **do not reuse version names that were previously used with endpointV1**.

E.g. I had a `testing-dot-MYPROJECT.appspot.com`.

I now use a different version: `test-dot-MYPROJECT.appspot.com`.

For the long answer, have a look at cputoaster's answer.