# 404 after migrating to Google Endpoints V2

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

We have succesfully used Endpoints V1 for couple of years in our app. Now when trying to migrate to Endpoints V2 it suddenly brakes by just simply not finding the EndpointsServlet and just returns 404 always.

- I am able to browse the api with https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/
- I can see that the request comes to the backend and one filter I am using
- but it never finds/reaches the EndpointsServlet or any of the Endpoints
- strangely it works in localhost devserver ??

Is this still a known issue (for some Apps) or how could I troubleshoot the case?

The 404 response looks like this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "\u003chtml\u003e\u003chead\u003e\n\u003cmeta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\"\u003e\n\u003ctitle\u003e404 Not Found\u003c/title\u003e\n\u003c/head\u003e\n\u003cbody text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff\u003e\n\u003ch1\u003eError: Not Found\u003c/h1\u003e\n\u003c/body\u003e\u003c/html\u003e\n"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "\u003chtml\u003e\u003chead\u003e\n\u003cmeta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\"\u003e\n\u003ctitle\u003e404 Not Found\u003c/title\u003e\n\u003c/head\u003e\n\u003cbody text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff\u003e\n\u003ch1\u003eError: Not Found\u003c/h1\u003e\n\u003c/body\u003e\u003c/html\u003e\n"
 }
}
```

Comment: There's an ongoing known issue that prevents the version change from working when you switch App Engine versions. Can you try visiting the versioned service hostname to see if it works? `https://version-dot-project.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer`.

Comment: Thanks @saiyr so you mean the Endpoints V2 have an issue when deployed to a versioned App Engine? I can see that the explorer shows the API but suffers from that "404 not found", similarly as when called from JavaScript front-end.

Comment: If you use the versioned URL on your API and it still doesn't work, then you likely made an error in your migration and more details are necessary.

Comment: @saiyr The migration instruction says like this: 
"Note: The old App Engine Maven plugin, with group com.google.appengine, is incompatible with the Endpoints Framework plugin. You must use the new version shown above."

Can you explain why the old App Engine Maven plugin is not anymore compatible with the Endpoints V2. This is my suspect for the moment. Changing the project deployment method is not trivial in my case.

And more, is it possible to debug somehow why I get 404 Not Found all the time when trying to call the Endpoints V2?

Comment: You can use the old Maven plugin with the v2 frameworks if you aren't using the v2 frameworks plugin. I believe it's related to the new plugins using gcloud, but I can't say for sure. Again, you should try hitting the versioned URL of your app to see if it works. This may be a manifestation of a bug for which we are rolling out a fix.

Comment: Ok I got those previous errors tackled by updating various version numbers jackson, guava, etc ... and now it works on localhost DevServer but still online I get only 404, I am using versioned URL like `GET https://[version]-[appId].appspot.com/_ah/api/api/v1/users/me` ... any ideas what could be still wrong? Or what to check?

Comment: Hi again @saiyr after some debugging I can see this kind of calls in StackDriver logs
`POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs`
and `POST /_ah/spi/[package].UserEndpoint.get` does these look ok for the Endpoints V2?

Comment: also I'm having problems with this in **web.xml**
`<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>` with that mapping the Servlet seems to be missing completely. But if I use the old URL `/_ah/api/*` Servlet is found but not really working.

Comment: Ok I found this answer and this resolved that 404 Not Found issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132787/versioning-with-endpoint-v2-on-gae?rq=1

Comment: @JariK May I ask you to post the solution to your original issue as an answer?

Comment: @GonçaloAlbino Well I did, but what I wrote was considered "too simple solution" and it was converted automatically to a comment by StackOverflow !!

Answer (score 2):

The solution for this was to use completely new un-used version name when deploying app with Endpoints V2, so instead of:

```
https://test-dot-[app_id].appspot.com (this used previously Endpoints V1)
```

use a brand new version name like e.g.

```
https://test-new-dot-[app_id].appspot.com
```

As said here: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/known-issues

> "...you must currently deploy to a new App Engine app version. Reusing an old app version may conflict with the old Endpoints deployment..."

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue when I had the SystemServiceServlet still configured to use the old url pattern.

**Correct:**

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Incorrect:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The servlet class for V2 is also changed to: `com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

1. You have this section in web.xml(no matter you have it in POM.XML or not!)

```html
 <!-- Wrap the backend with Endpoints Frameworks v2. --> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.echo.Echo,com.example.echo.Foo</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
<!--     Route API method requests to the backend. -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

2. Your correct and consistently same  {ProjectId} in web.xml, pom.xml, appengine-web.xml. If using gcloud shell, check your current active configuration and its project.
3. For safer-side, deploy your app on new version while migrating from old framework V1 to V2.